Conversion of a result number to a specified unit of measure
It's a very simple question, but I need to know how to convert numbers, because in several cases I ran into this topic and felt unsure about this.
So for example we're counting a unit measure of time, the result number is: 1.11810^-5 and in order to convert it to microseconds, we need to divide by 10, to have -6 in the power, so basically it'd looks like this: 0.11810^-6 = 0.118 microseconds.
Is it right?
I'll be really grateful if you could help me.
Thanks a lot!
Norbert

In your calculation you did not change the mantissa at all.

Presumably the result of your calculation has a unit.  You need to figure out what it is based on the units of the data you used in the calculation.  If it is seconds and you want to report the result in microseconds you multiply by $1$ in the form $\frac {10^6 \text{ microseconds}}{1 \text{ second}}$  In your example, if the result is $0.11810 \cdot 10^{-5}$ seconds, you would say $0.11810 \cdot 10^{-5}$ seconds $\cdot \frac {10^6 \text{ microseconds}}{1 \text{ second}}=1.1810 \text { microseconds}$.  Note that you are multiplying the value to compensate for reducing the exponent.

Yes, so basically the smaller quantity measure unit requires the moving of the mantissa.
If we'd like to round our quantity (0.11810*10^-5) to microseconds, then we divide the exponent by 10, and at the same time we move the mantissa right according to the smaller quantity.
